# Inmobi Banner ads in screens

Tags: banner-ads, inmobi

I am using Inmobi to publish ads in my iOS app. The banner ads are appearing in all screens. I don't want it to appear in one screen as it is blocking the button. Any solutions?

Update: I wrote to inmobi support. Now my account is made inactive without my permission. Its more than 24 hours but no resolution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sohan from InMobi here.

The banner ad is a UIView. Just hide it or remove it from the superview in the screen in which you don't want it to show. Thats it, really!

Answer (score -1):

Use setFrame() to your banner ads and adjust it as you like.